# Genetics-healthy foods-workouts result get taller

Tags: workout-types

Genetics are 70% or 80% that influence how tall we will be. 20% is food how healhty we eat.I came to ask three questions.First, workouts arent influence our body how tall could we be?I give an example, muscles, when we give effort to build on biceps we can make it bigger if we try for a long period.As a result ,what about hanging workout,this workout  influence the body to "become" taller or not?Second,when someone take 4inches lets say he takes which part of the body increase legs or his back? Third, i am hanging everyday at moring for 10 minutes my age is 26. If it could be to take an inch could this a good way? Thanks

Comment: No it isnt.This "answers" only my third question but not good because even in third question i refer other workout.

Comment: Yes, it is. Height, barring disease or injury is genetic. You can't get more.

Answer (score 1):

> "Genetics are 70% or 80% that influence how tall we will be. 20% is
> food how healthy we eat."

Not true. It is 100% Genetics. Nutrition can only influence height if you are malnourished and have a disorder as a result that affects your bones.

> First, workouts arent influence our body how tall could we be?I give an example, muscles, when we give effort to build on biceps we can make it bigger if we try for a long period. As a result ,what about hanging workout ,this workout influence the body to "become" taller or not?

You are making your biceps bigger through muscle development. The length of your upper-arm is the same, determined by your bone size, genetics. Hanging only will make your arms temporarily longer (by 1 inch at most) due to the joints being streached. Your arms will quickly return to their normal length.

> Second,when someone take 4inches lets say he takes which part of the body increase legs or his back?

This makes no sense.

> Third, i am hanging everyday at moring for 10 minutes my age is 26. If it could be to take an inch could this a good way? Thanks

It won't make you taller.

Now, repeat after me:

## I cannot alter my height permanently through exercise or nutrition, it is 100% determined by my genetics.

Comment: Irony text. 100% first time i hear it. Search it better.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Ι mean first time reading this is 100% by genetics